# The output always comes a garbage value in periods of pendulum question in C

Tags: c

**Reference Image**

[image]

The output always comes: 6.35 (I think it's a garbage value)
the code is

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>
float formula(float,float);

int main()
{
    float l=0,a=0;

    printf("enter the length of the pendulum(l)\n");
    scanf("%f",&l);
    printf("Enter the angle of displacemnt(a)\n");
    scanf("%f",&a);
    printf("the length is %0.2f\n",l);
    printf("the angle of displacemnt is %0.2f\n",a);
    printf("the period of pendulum is %0.2f",formula(l,a));
    return 0;
   
    
}
float formula(float l, float a)
{
    float P=0,ran=0,g = 9.8;
    ran = (l/g) * (1 + ((1/4)*(pow((float)(sin((double)a/2)),2))));
    P = 2 * M_PI * ((float)sqrt((double)ran));
    return P;
}
```

I don't know what is happening

Comment: `1/4` is `0` because it uses integer arithmetic. Use `0.25`

Comment: Aside: you dodge back and forth between `float` and `double`. It would be better to work in `double` throughout, which is the default type for floating point literals and variadic function arguments (besides having wider range and better precision). Save `float` for when you have memory constraints, or where `double` is not supported by the hardware and/or a library.

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify this implementation by using doubles or floats exclusively. The 1/4 integer division yields 0. Here's an example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

float formula(float l, float a)
{
    float ran = l / 9.8f * (1.0f + powf(sinf(a/2.0f), 2.0f) / 4.0f);

    return 2.0f * (float) M_PI * sqrtf(ran);
}

int main(void)
{
    float l;
    float a;

    printf("Enter the length of the pendulum(l): ");
    scanf("%f", &l);
    printf("Enter the angle of displacemnt(a): ");
    scanf("%f", &a);

    printf("The length is %0.2f\n", l);
    printf("The angle of displacemnt is %0.2f\n", a);
    printf("The period of pendulum is %0.2f\n", formula(l,a));

    return 0;
}
```